# Bluetooth push application

Tags: design

I am considering the technical viability of software that I want to write.

Is there a way that I can push data to a phone (iPhone or Andriod) via Bluetooth without pairing with it?

I want to be able to walk into a room and have a computer push data to my phone when I get a certain distance from it, or push data to any phone automatically when it comes within a certain distance to a Bluetooth-ready device?

Comment: Pretty sure you always have to pair, but pairing can be automatic when the device is within range (my phone pairs to my car automatically, for example).

Comment: I don't know to be honest, but for the sake of all that is good and secure in this world, I would wish deeply that this was not possible.

Comment: @AnnaLear however, you likely paired it once not automatically before (at least, that's the case with my phone and car).

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, it does have to be set up at first.

Comment: Look at [tod](http://todhq.com/) for one such device and investigate the bluetooth 4.0 spec.  I highly doubt that bluetooth allows for pushing arbitrary data to a device that isn't paired (or specifically configured to allow such activity).

Comment: @AnnaLear and that is the pairing that is done (and remembered).  To be able to push data to an arbitrary phone (such as your neighbors when he walks into his domicile that is within range, or a stranger walking down the sidewalk) would be disconcerting.  Consider also someone having such a device in their car and driving down the interstate pushing data to all nearby drivers.  I kind of doubt that this is permitted by the spec.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if you want to completely skip the pairing process or just avoid having to enter in a pin.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885438/bluetooth-pairing-without-user-confirmation) has a number of useful answers related to both sides of that question, albeit with an emphasis on android.  Short answer is, yes, you may be able to do what you're asking in limited circumstances.

The [Wikipedia entry on Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) has a number of interesting components, and I would recommend looking at section 7.3 regarding connections and bonding and section 8 regarding security.

Finally, [this article](http://hassam.hubpages.com/hub/Types-Of-Bluetooth-Hacks-And-Its-Security-Issues) goes over a number of prevalent hacks against bluetooth.  They don't tell you how, and I wouldn't encourage exploiting those vulnerabilities, but it may be enough information for you to discover a legitimate way of doing what your describing.  And honestly, it was pretty easy to google, so it's not like I'm giving away secrets here.